# Rails Sort/Group by dynamic field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, sinatra

I'm working on a rails app that is passing serialized values in a JSON dump to the client. I need the requirements to be sorted in a specific order, with objects that contain equal "deadline_dates" to be grouped together. That field is dynamic and many of my objects don't contain that field at all.

Here is what my model looks like:

```
#------ app/models/program_requirement.rb ------#
class ProgramRequirement < ActiveRecord::Base
 include HasFields

 belongs_to :program
 has_many :responses
 has_many :applications, through: :responses

 store_accessor :fields, :deadline_date
end
```

Here is the method I'm using to pass the objects into my serializer:

```
#------ app/models/program.rb ------#
def sorted_program_requirements
self.program_requirements.sort_by{|a| [a.deadline, a.position]}.map {
  |requirement| ProgramRequirementSerializer.new(requirement, root: false) }
end
```

The sorting for the "deadline" and "position" values works fine, but some reason, I'm unable to sort by including a param into my sort_by method such as:

```
a.fields[:deadline_date]
```

I've attempted using group_by, but that also doesn't seem to do what I'd expect. I just want to group requirements by equal deadline_dates if they exist, and then sort the rest by the other two static fields.

Any help is appreciated!

#### UPDATE

Output from: program_requirements.each { |pr| p pr.fields[:deadline_date] }

```
[#<ProgramRequirement:0x007fb198a12d58
  id: 126,
  program_id: 1159,
  title: "Req",
  deadline: "manual",
  position: 1,
  fields: {"deadline_date"=>"2015-09-16"}
 #<ProgramRequirement:0x007fb198a12bf0
  id: 127,
  program_id: 1159,
  title: "Req",
  deadline: "initial",
  position: 2,
  fields: {}
 #<ProgramRequirement:0x007fb198a12a60
  id: 132,
  program_id: 1159,
  title: "Req",
  deadline: "precampaign",
  position: 3,
  fields: {}
 #<ProgramRequirement:0x007fb198a128d0
  id: 133,
  program_id: 1159,
  title: "t444",
  description: nil,
  deadline: "manual",
  position: 4,
  fields: {"deadline_date"=>"2015-09-16"}
]
```

Comment: What do you mean by `I'm unable to sort by including a param into my sort_by method`, what result do you get? Any error messages, or is it just sorts incorrectly?

Comment: @AlexeyShein Sorry for the confusion -- no errors are produced, but there isn't any difference in the way the array is sorted had I not included that parameter. Now that I think about it -- the issue may be because the "deadline_dates" are stored as strings rather than dates, so its possible that it doesn't recognize that I want the strings to be equal in what they contain vs. being equal in length..

Comment: Well, they at least have to obey the string sorting, and if they're all dates they should have equal length, like `2015-09-13` (I don't know what format you're using :) )

Comment: Yep I see whats going on but I'm  unsure if this is something that should be fixed on the server. I have to convert the deadline_dates to actual dates if they exist and compare them.. The situation I'm running into is that if you create a requirement with a date of lets say "2001" then create another with "2002" then make another with "2001", since the strings are all the same length, they're actually grouped as 2001,2002,2001 vs. grouping both 2001's together. Sorry if I'm being a bit unclear -- still getting the hang of rails.

Comment: Ok, so each `program_requirement` stores 1 date or many dates in a `fields[:deadline_date]` column? Could you update a question with output of `program_requirements.each { |pr| p pr.fields[:deadline_date] }`, please?

Comment: @AlexeyShein thanks for looking into this with me -- a program requirement can store only one date in the fields[:deadline_date] field. A date is only stored there if the "deadline" field is "manual". I've updated the question with the output.

Comment: Ok, that makes things clearer. One more question: do you want to collapse  objects with equal dates into one (i.e. sql-like `GROUP BY deadline_date`) or just sort them, so they would stand together (i.e. sql-like 'ORDER BY deadline_date`)?

Comment: If I understand correctly, just ORDER BY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so if you just need to sort by the `deadline_date`, well, sort by it:

```
program_requirements.sort_by { |a| a.deadline_date.to_s }
```

Since not every `program_requirement` contains this field, you'll need to convert all `nil`s to strings, so they can be compared to each other. This way all `program_requirement`s that don't contain `deadline_date`s will be grouped at the top, and everybody else will be sorted on the way to bottom.

Comment: Oh so simple! Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't try it yourself! By the way, does it work without `.to_s` construct? I'm not quite familiar with `store_accessor` construct.

Comment: I was a bit confused as to how ruby's sort_by method worked. I was under the impression that it wouldn't sort the string by deadline dates correctly unless I converted them using the to_date method, which was what I had been trying. Without using to_s, manual deadlines are grouped together, but they are arranged in the order that they're created vs. the deadline_date order... It doesn't help my case that I'm relying on three different variables to sort this array..

Comment: Thank you for clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Sorting in ruby is not a good idea. Doing it in Sql it much faster:

```
program_requirements.order(deadline_date: :asc) or :desc
```